# Call to undefined function mime_content_type(), can't change server settings

Tags: php, mime-types

I have the error found in the title (Call to undefined function `mime_content_type()`). I've read about re-compiling PHP, as well as using `finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);`. The problem with the latter is that my PHP version is 5.2.15, which is too old to support `finfo`, so I switched to `mime_content_type()` (which is cleaner, in my opinion), but my server doesn't support that either!

My question is this: can I use `ini_set()` to set a value so I can use `mime_content_type()`, or is there another (hackier maybe) way to get a file's mime type?

Here is my PHPinfo(): http://staging.cliquesoft.org/cs/infos.php

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the reimplementation from http://upgradephp.berlios.de/. It defines te `mime_content_type` function if missing. You find it in `include("ext/mime.php");`

There's also a version in PEARs [PHP_Compat](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat).

Comment: Thanks very much - I'm using the `upgrade.php` solution. Irritatingly, it's giving the MIME of the file as `application/octet-stream` when it's actually just JPEG... Any ideas?

Comment: Wait... It works well for PNG (`image/png`), but not for JPEG.

Comment: It depends on the mime-magic file. It looks for `/usr/share/misc/magic.mime` or `/etc/mime-magic` or the php.ini setting `mime_magic.magicfile`. Then it might have quirks with some variants of the magic database to determine the best match. It also might just be that your file is inaccessible.

Comment: Maybe try PHP_Compat after all. It might have more clever algorithms.

Comment: Yes, it's a bit more difficult because it is a PEAR package. But you can just dowload it and extract the contents somewhere. include() the main script as usual, or just the one you need: `include("Compat/Function/mime_content_type.php");`

Comment: Oh I just noticed, it uses a really mean and simple trick: `$mime = exec("file -iL $filename 2>/dev/null");` Maybe that alone would work for you?

Comment: You, sir, should be named 'God' - I used the following snippet to get me the MIME type: `$mime = exec("file -i {$_FILES['sponsor_logo_file']['tmp_name']}");
  $mime = str_replace("{$_FILES['sponsor_logo_file']['tmp_name']}: ", "", $mime);` The `str_replace()` is to get rid of the filename at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Take care that you sometimes get a `;charset=` parameter with the mime type. Maybe use a regex or `$mime = trim(strtok(substr(strrchr($mime, ":"), 1), ";"))` instead of the replace. -- Also I discovered the bug in the aforementioned mime function now.. :}

Comment: Thanks for putting the effort into helping me mario! I've amended my code as follows: `file --mime-type <file_name_here> 2>/dev/null` The `2>/dev/null` throws the second result into void as per the original command.